# can we wear embroidered animal figures during Namaz?

Tags: salat, clothing

I heared that embroidery patterns including animal figures (horse, ducks, pandas, etc.) is religiously objectionable .we can't wear these clothes during Namaz. Can I wear those  clothes (t-shirts) during Nmaz...?